# iframe positioning on window not div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Im currently improving my Website www.herget.design. Therefore i use the CMS Koken (koken.me) which managing my content and is really code.

Now I want to add the functionality, that If you play video it willbe displayed all over the window. But my cms generates a list, that looks like:

```
<ul class="content-list">
<span class="k-infinite-load">
<li>
<span class="img-wrap">

<iframe class="k-custom-source" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/141314866?username=1&assign_tag=1&tags=1&portrait=0&title=0&byline=0&autoplay=0&loop=0&color=d8d9da&api=1&player_id=koken_vimeo_49" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" title="Bootshaus Blackbox // CLUBBUSTERS 18.09.2015" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

            <span class="img-data">
                <!-- ......... -->
            </span>
</span>
</li>
```

My Problem is, that when I use the CSS to animate and scale the iFrame, it will be transofrmed only in its span/li.
CSS:

```
Vimeo_Ani_IN {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    animation-name: VIMEO_IN;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.Vimeo_Ani_OUT {
     animation-name: VIMEO_OUT;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

@keyframes VIMEO_IN {
    0%   {}
    100% {
        position:relative;
        top: 10px;
        height: 80%; /* fallback if needed */
        height: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 40%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
@keyframes VIMEO_OUT {
    0%   {
        height: 100%;
        }
    100% {
    }
}
```

Has anybody ideas how to scale it to the window, without removing the CMS given structure and only manipulating the iframe? Of course it should be responsive.

Greetz and thanks to everybody who answears.
Marius

Comment: Try using `vh` for view height and `vw` for view width instead of percents? i.e. `7vh` would be 7% of the view height, or the window height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
/* This you may already have, just check first */
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


/*Be careful with this. I suggest finding a specific class or parent instead of ALL LIs */
li{list-style-type:none;}

/* This gives you the full screen window   */

span.img-wrap {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
}

span.img-wrap iframe {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVamYL)

Comment: Thanks 

span.img-wrap iframe {
   width: 100%;
}

worked! :)

Comment: any ideas how center the iframe then?

Comment: If there is a container that holds this iframe, center the container div with margin: 0 auto; That is an educated guess. I can't tell for sure without looking at more of your code

Comment: the container are 100%. but they are in li's and they need to stay in its 24% width to stay in the order... maybe i do a workaround with margins... thanks for your answear

Comment: No problem. Play around with the LI's display and width and see if you can control it from there. But to center the item, you need to either give the parent a text-align:center or a margin:0 auto to the item itself (iframe in this case)